# How to deploy Java application on a web server

Tags: java, heroku, webserver, openshift

For 3-4 days I am trying to deploy a java application on web server but every time getting different type of error.So far I have tried to host my application on openshift,heroku but everytime getting different type of error.Can someone tell me a good free hosting website where I can host my java application.My application size is 1.5 gb.
Thank You in advance.

Comment: Hi and welcome. Please read here -> stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask , then edit your question accordigly!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you can use cloud service for this. My preference is Google Cloud. Maybe try Azure or AWS.

Java on Google Cloud https://cloud.google.com/java/

Comment: Thank You @mesutpiskin for responding,this solved my problem perfectly.